# Using blocking in propensity score analysis?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, confounding, subset, blocking

I'm considering blocking my analysis dataset on one or two key variables prior to a standard sub-classification propensity score analysis.

For example, if my dataset (which contains member level pre- and post-treatment period hospital utilization outcomes) is blocked on the # of hospital ED visits during the pre-treatment time period: 0, 1, or 2+ visits, then sub-classification based on propensity scores would be conducted on both the treatment and control groups within each block.

The overall Average Treatment Effect (ATE) could then be calculated as a weighted average of the ATEs within each block.

Is this a valid approach to PSA to improve the balance of treatment and control members being compared?

Comment: It can definitely be done... the question is why... If you are afraid you might have substantial imbalances in cases and controls, then it is a reasonable approach, especially to ensure external validity. However, I would also consider inverse probability of treatment weighting if you are afraid having unbalanced groups.

Comment: @Joe_74 Thanks Joe. My primary worry is that several covariates in the study carry more weight than others. Since we're measuring the change in # ED visits after the treatment, it would make sense to block on # of pre-treatment ED visits in order to control for regression to the mean effects. I think this would also go over well with our clients who are not statistics savvy.

Comment: I see. I have expanded my comments into a reasonable answer.

Comment: Green & Stuart (2014) [dx.doi.org/10.1037/a0036515] discusses this issue precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your concern as the scientific literature on propensity scores and blocking is difficult to search given that blocking is typically used after propensity score estimation.

You basically ask instead if blocking before estimating the propensity scores (and using them) is reasonable and valid. In general terms yes, even if you could end up loosing statistical precision and increasing confidence intervals. In your specific case, I am not sure you really need to do it, but I don't think it would harm your analysis, unless your sample is very small (which I guess is quite unlikely).

The most appropriate scenario in which to enforce pre-emptive blocking would be however a different one. For instance, imagine you want to compare the impact of coronary revascularization after finding myocardial ischemia at myocardial perfusion imaging (MPI) (e.g. [Nudi et al, J Nucl Cardiol 2016](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs12350-016-0504-5)). The typical approach would be just to conduct a propensity matched analysis on the whole dataset, possibly after missing data imputation. The issue here is that many people (say 60%) undergo MPI after exercise stress, which generates many important covariates for propensity score estimation, such as maximum workload, whereas other patients cannot exercise, and undergo pharmacologic stress, which does not yield such data. In a similar scenario, simply imputing missing data would be clinically wrong, and statistically risky. Instead, the correct approach is definitely separate estimation of propensity scores and matching in each block (exercise stress, pharmacologic stress), followed by computing average treatment effects (and the homogeneity between the two blocks as well).

Comment: Great answer. My sample size is over 31,000, but with only about 350 treatment subjects and the rest controls. I suggested exact matching to my supervisor, but we're locked into propensity matching based on earlier promises we've made to our client. Therefore blocking on the most important variables (which might be established from simple regression coefficients) seemed a good compromise.

Comment: @RobertF Do proceed with blocking followed by propensity matching, but also consider IPTW as a sensitivity analysis to avoid discarding so many controls.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I considered IPTW & haven't completely ruled it out. There's a chapter in Guo & Fraser's 2015 textbook (Propensity Score Analysis: Statistical Methods and Applications) on IPTW, where some limitations to IPTW are mentioned. I went with subclassification since it's fairly simple to explain, avoids discarding controls, and doesn't necessarily impose a parametric model on the data.

Comment: @RobertF I am fine with your take. In the end I don't think there is much risk in loosing power or precision... And anyway, I would doubt any analysis in which PS and IPTW disagree...